# Eigen slerp (estimate) rotation matrix from 3 rotation matrices not 2

Tags: c++, eigen3, panoramas, 360-panorama

I'm writing a panorama stitcher in C++ and I use slerp (spherical linear interpolation) and Quaternions to estimate the rotation matrix from adjacent images (using the Eigen library) when I can't get enough features to match. 
I can make a qualified guess that an image should be between the two others in a multi-row when let's say only one image can't be connected to others.
It works kind of ok to this but I would like to improve it by using slerp (or something else) to do the estimate from more adjacent images.

Anyone that knows such a way? it doesn't need to be using the Eigen lib.

Currently, I do like this
[image]

But would like to improve with doing something like this using 1,3 and 5 (and even 4 and 5 if that is better)
[image]

Edit 1:
From the comment by @nico-schertler I got an idea how would I go about to get the slerp fraction for 5 between 4 and 6? I would then use this fraction as my input to the slerp for 2 between 1 and 3 which currently is 0.5

Comment: What would be the assumption behind this approach? That image 2 should be horizontally aligned to image 5? I doubt that this is a valid assumption. The assumption is essential in finding a solution. Simple averages will not get you far because this will pull image 2 down towards 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Image 2 should be vertically aligned to image 5 and be aligned to the horizontal arc between 1 and 3